# Configuring apache DocumentRoot and spring boot

Tags: apache2, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot with an embedded tomcat server and I want to create a VirtualHost entry from my apache server to my standalone application.  What would the DocumentRoot be in this case?

Comment: I managed to get it working by using the path to the jar file.  I've since uninstalled apache2 and installed nginx.  I've configured it the same way as I did apache however I will try your method and see if I can get that configuration working too.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a DocumentRoot, use Apache as a reverse proxy

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/TomcatReverseProxy

Something like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myhost.name
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080
</VirtualHost>
```